# Passing SQLite to new activity not working

Tags: android

I'm having a issue trying to pass the data from my SQLite DB to the next activity.

Here is my .java

```
public class TimsFavs extends ListActivity implements OnItemClickListener {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

    String col0,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col7;

    // Database results

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.timsfavs);
        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

        //---get all Locations---
        db.open();

        Cursor c =  db.getAllLocation();

        if (c.moveToFirst())
        {
            do {

                col0 =  c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBAdapter.KEY_ROWID));
                col1 =  c.getString(1);
                col2 =  c.getString(2);
                col3 =  c.getString(3);
                col4 =  c.getString(4);
                col5 =  c.getString(5);
                col6 =  c.getString(6);
                col7 =  c.getString(7);

                results.add(col2);

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        db.close();

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));
        ListView lv;
        lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(83, 05, 14));
        lv.setOnItemClickListener((OnItemClickListener) this);

    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> TimsFavs, View view, int position, long id) {

        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), TimsFavsMore.class);

        i.putExtra("ct_id_pass", col0);
        i.putExtra("ct_storeid_pass", col1);
        i.putExtra("ct_address_pass", results.get(position));
        i.putExtra("ct_city_pass", col3);
        i.putExtra("ct_province_pass", col4);
        i.putExtra("ct_country_pass", col5);
        i.putExtra("ct_pcode_pass", col6);
        i.putExtra("ct_phnum_pass", col7);

        startActivity(i);
        finish();

    }
}
```

here are my other 2 files

DBAdapter.java

```
public class DBAdapter 
{
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_PHONE = "phone";
    public static final String KEY_STNUMBER = "stnumber";
    public static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "address";
    public static final String KEY_CITY = "city";
    public static final String KEY_PROVINCE = "province";
    public static final String KEY_COUNTRY = "country";
    public static final String KEY_PCODE = "pcode";    
    private static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "timsfavs";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "location";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table location (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "phone text not null, stnumber text not null, "
        + "address text not null, city text not null, "
        + "province text not null, country text not null, "
        + "pcode text not null);";

    private final Context context; 

    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) 
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion 
                    + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS location");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }    

    //---opens the database---
    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---    
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //---insert a title into the database---
    public long insertLocation(String phone, String stnumber, String address, String city, String province, String country, String pcode) 
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);
        initialValues.put(KEY_STNUMBER, stnumber);
        initialValues.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
        initialValues.put(KEY_CITY, city);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PROVINCE, province);
        initialValues.put(KEY_COUNTRY, country);
        initialValues.put(KEY_PCODE, pcode);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    //---deletes a particular title---
    public boolean deleteLocation(String rowId) 
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + 
                "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    //---retrieves all the titles---
    public Cursor getAllLocation() 
    {

        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                KEY_ROWID, 
                KEY_PHONE,
                KEY_STNUMBER,
                KEY_ADDRESS,
                KEY_CITY,
                KEY_PROVINCE,
                KEY_COUNTRY,
                KEY_PCODE}, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null, 
                null,
                null);

    }

    //---retrieves a particular title---
    public Cursor getLocation(long rowId) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {
                        KEY_ROWID,
                        KEY_PHONE, 
                        KEY_STNUMBER,
                        KEY_ADDRESS,
                        KEY_CITY,
                        KEY_PROVINCE,
                        KEY_COUNTRY,
                        KEY_PCODE
                        }, 
                        KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, 
                        null,
                        null,
                        null,
                        null, 
                        null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    //---updates a title---
    public boolean updateLocation(long rowId, String phone, 
    String stnumber, String address, String city, 
    String province, String country, String pcode) 
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_PHONE, phone);
        args.put(KEY_STNUMBER, stnumber);
        args.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
        args.put(KEY_CITY, city);
        args.put(KEY_PROVINCE, province);
        args.put(KEY_COUNTRY, country);
        args.put(KEY_PCODE, pcode);
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, 
                         KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }
}
```

TimsFavsMore.java

```
public class TimsFavsMore extends Activity {
    DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

    String rowId;

     @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.timsfavsmore);

            Intent i = getIntent();
            Bundle b = i.getExtras();

             final String rowId = b.getString("ct_id_pass");
             final String phnum = b.getString("ct_phnum_pass");
             final String storeid = b.getString("ct_storeid_pass");
             final String address = b.getString("ct_address_pass");
             final String city = b.getString("ct_city_pass");
             final String province = b.getString("ct_province_pass");
             final String country = b.getString("ct_country_pass");
             final String pcode = b.getString("ct_pcode_pass");

            TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
            title.setText(Html.fromHtml("<br>Row ID: " + rowId + "<br><b><u>Location Address:</u></b><br><br>Store #" + storeid + "<br><br>" + address + "<br>" + city + ", " + province + "<br>" + country +"<br>" + pcode +"<br><br><b><u>Contact Info:</b></u><br><br>" + phnum +"<br>"));

    // open to Nav

    final Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gohere);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String uri = "google.navigation:q=Tim%20Hortons,%20" + address + ",%20" + city + ",%20" + province + ",%20" + pcode + "";
            Intent i2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            startActivity(i2);

        }
    });

    // open to maps

    final Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.showmap);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String uri2 = "geo:0,0?q=Tim%20Hortons,%20" + address + ",%20" + city + ",%20" + province + ",%20" + pcode + "";
            Intent i3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri2));
            startActivity(i3);

        }
    });

    // Add to My Timmies List

    final Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.removefav);
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

          //---add 2 SQLite---

            db.open();

            if (db.deleteLocation(rowId))
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " Delete successful.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Delete failed.", 
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();            
            db.close();

           Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyTimmies.class);
           startActivity(i);
           finish();

        }
    });


    final Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.favsdone);
    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

       Intent i4 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyTimmies.class);
           startActivity(i4);
           finish();

        }
    });
     }
}
```

Comment: col2 is out of scope in the onItemClick method - you've declared it as a String inside the do loop in onCreate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I misread your code, hopefully you didn't read this yet!

Your ListView's data is fetched from a Cursor, there is an easier way to handle all of this by using a [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html), this will populate the ListView from the cursor and when you click an item it will let you know which row of the Cursor a clicked item is from.

Comment: if i add that string line i still get a java error at i.putExtra("ct_address_pass", col2[position]); if i change it to i.putExtra("ct_address_pass", col2); i no longer get the java error but get a null so no data is being passed.

Comment: So after i added your string and changed the putextra i changed  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { to public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> TimsFavs, View view, int position, long id) { and it worked.

Comment: @PsychoDogg try using `results.get(position)` to get the string from that row, since results is holding all of the strings you find as you work through the Cursor. Generally this is still something you would better handle with a CursorAdapter if you are going to use Cursors in your Activities.

Comment: I don't know where to add `results.get(position)` to make this work. anywhere i put it i get errors or when i get no error it just doesn't change anything.

Comment: I have also been trying to use a SimpleCursorAdapter but this is giving me issues as well as im still trying to a grab on to cursor.

Comment: Can anyone show my how to add results.get(position) to work since I cant make heads or tails of SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: @PsychoDogg As I see it, in onCreate you query the database and get a cursor of results.

You then loop through the cursor and add whatever is in col2 to an ArrayList of Strings. This list is what is being used to create your ListView, so whatever is in position X in your ArrayList is in position X on your ListView.

OnItemClick tells you what position in the list was clicked, so that same position in your ArrayList represents the item being clicked. So if position = 5, then results.get(5) is what was clicked, so you can use that value in i.putExtra("ct_address_pass", result.get(position));

Comment: ok that worked but i guess i can only have 1 item cared over. I guess i have to rethink this whole thing. I have had no issue building this app other then this part and its the last thing hold it back from beta lol.

Comment: ok so `i.putExtra("ct_address_pass", result.get(position));` shows the right address. is there a way to carry the other values with it?

Comment: @PsychoDogg you can make a new Class that represents the data in your table. I'm not sure what is in that table but lets say it a person. You can make a new Class called Person and give it various methods like setName, setAddress, setCity, etc. In your `do` loop above you can create a new Person object and instead of using the col1,2, etc Strings you can do Person person = new Person then person.setName(c.getString(0)); person.setAddress(c.getString(1)); and so on. Then you can change `result` to an ArrayList of Person objects instead of Strings and add "person" to it after each loop.

Comment: Continued...In your "Person" class, make sure it implements Serializable. So "public class Person implements Serializable". This way you can add it directly to the intent.

So at the end you can do i.putExtra("person",result.get(position)); <-- This time you are adding an entire person to the intent, not just a String. In the next activity you would need to do:
`Person incomingPerson = (Person) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("person");`

Comment: now I'm more confused then before. I have been trying to get this to work for over a week now. I have added all 3 files in hopes there is a fast fix.

Comment: I'll break down the changes by file:
1) Make a new Person class: http://pastebin.com/z06afWng
2) Have your TimsFavs Activity use this object to save entries, you don't need the col1,2,3 etc strings anymore: http://pastebin.com/QAcK5gk7
3) Now your FavsMore Activity can read this information: http://pastebin.com/HKy52HqP

Note that your FavsMore activity won't work quite yet, you will have to replace your Strings with calls to the Person object, I made a note of it in the comments.

Tell me if there are any problems there, I mostly did it directly on PasteBin.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! Thank you! With a bit of modification that was it. I have it showing the right info and deleting as well.